# Uploading csv into R for using "Ramf" package

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to analyze some arbuscular mycorrhizal data and found the Ramf package (I think part of devtools) to use. I formatted my csv in the format suggested and cannot get R to load the data to even do the readData() function. I have tried different ways of selecting the csv file and variations of the recommended code from https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2019.01184/full#f1
but none of it has been working for me. The csv downloads as a value that says "character empty" instead of the 7-column data frame that I would expect.
When I use this code: Ramf.data<-read.csv(file.choose())
I can see the data in a data frame, but then when I go to do any actions in the Ramf package (including readData) I get this error message:

```
Error in `vroom::vroom()`:
! `file` is not one of the supported inputs:
• A filepath or character vector of filepaths
• A connection or list of connections
• Literal or raw input
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─Ramf::readData((as.data.frame("Ramf5")), type = "grid")
 2.   ├─base::suppressMessages(read_csv(infile))
 3.   │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 4.   └─readr::read_csv(infile)
 5.     └─vroom::vroom(...)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 3 hidden frames.
```

I want to look at the data frame using readData() and use the other functions in Ramf as well, but I can't use the actions without the mentioned error message. Here is what I have for code so far (that has not been working):

```
#Ramf
Ramf.data<-read.csv(file.choose())
Ramf.6 <- dir(system.file("Ramf.csv", package = "Ramf"), full.names = TRUE, pattern = "grid.csv")
readData((as.data.frame("Ramf.data")), type="grid")
readData(Ramf.6, type="grid")
```

Comment: Try `readData(file.choose(), type="grid")` The documentation asks for a path the the CSV file, not the contents of the CSV file. What does `Ramf.6` return? Does `file.exists(Ramf.6)` return true?